# Plotly: How to add borders and sidelabels to subplots, and syncronize panning?

Tags: python, plotly

The following graph is my attempt to use Plotly in Python (code at the very bottom) to do 2x2 plot.
[image]

I am trying to improve the graph but I can't seem to do the following:

1. Borders on each of the subplots
2. Synchronize panning and zooming across all the plots. Although I am using shared_xaxes and shared_yaxes, it only works for the row and column of the subplot. So if I pan around on the lower left graph, the upper right graph remains unmoved.
3. Sidelabels to label the subplots. See for e.g. [image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code so far.

```
import plotly.offline as poff
import plotly.tools as tls

x = list(range(10,20))
y = x
y1 = [10-i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i-5) for i in x]
y3 = [abs(2*i- 5) for i in x]

fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                        vertical_spacing=0.01,
                        horizontal_spacing=0.01, print_grid=True)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y, 'name':'A1'},), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y1, 'name':'B2'},), 2, 2)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y2, 'name':'A2'},), 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y3, 'name':'B1'},), 1, 2)

fig['layout'].update(title='Multiple Subplots')
url = poff.plot(fig, filename="test23.html")
```

Comment: @Spinot8 How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a suggestion that should be ***very*** close to 100%, at least regarding what's actually possible at the moment:

**1.** Subplot borders: `fig_update_xaxes(mirror=True)`

**2.** You're already as close as you're going to get at the moment

**3.** Sidelabels: `fig['layout']['xaxis']['title']='Label x-axis 1'`

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#import plotly.offline as poff
#import plotly.tools as tls

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

x = list(range(10,20))
y = x
y1 = [10-i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i-5) for i in x]
y3 = [abs(2*i- 5) for i in x]

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                    #vertical_spacing=0.1,
                    #horizontal_spacing=0.05,
                    print_grid=True,)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y, 'name':'A1'},), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y1, 'name':'B2'},), 2, 2)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y2, 'name':'A2'},), 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter({'x':x, 'y':y3, 'name':'B1'},), 1, 2)

fig['layout'].update(title='Multiple Subplots')

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)

# edit axis labels
fig['layout']['xaxis']['title']='Label x-axis 1'
fig['layout']['xaxis2']['title']='Label x-axis 2'

fig['layout']['xaxis3']['title']='Label x-axis 3'
fig['layout']['xaxis4']['title']='Label x-axis 4'

fig['layout']['yaxis']['title']='Label y-axis 1'
fig['layout']['yaxis2']['title']='Label y-axis 2'

fig['layout']['yaxis3']['title']='Label x-axis 3'
fig['layout']['yaxis4']['title']='Label x-axis 4'

fig.show()
```