# Is there a way to add a margin line in Python-Plotly charts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

By default, Plotly charts does not have "lines" in the margins of the plot area.

I can define lines in the axis X and Y, but not in all plot area.

Using `"template": "simple_white"` in the layout, I can obtain the image bellow.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y = np.sin(x)
layout = {"template":"simple_white"}
data = go.Scatter(x=x,y=y)
fig = go.Figure(data,layout)
fig.show()
```

Image obtained with Plotly

[image]

Is there a way to obtain a image with Plotly like the one bellow, i.e. with lines around the plot area?

It is made with matplotlib package. I mean: can I have a image like this, but with Plotly package?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Image obtained with Matplotlib

[image]

EDIT:

A similar question can be found at:

[Plotly: How to add borders and sidelabels to subplots, and syncronize panning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147713/plotly-how-to-add-borders-and-sidelabels-to-subplots-and-syncronize-panning)

However, I would like to maintain this one for other users, because it is right straight to the point of putting borders in a single plot. The other question includes other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use another well-hidden Plotly attribute [mirror](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-mirror). Update your layout like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
layout = dict(
    template="simple_white",
    xaxis=dict(ticks="outside", mirror=True, showline=True),
    yaxis=dict(ticks="outside", mirror=True, showline=True),
)
data = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)
fig = go.Figure(data, layout)

fig.show()
```

This shows:
[image: d image]